# Why is iframe call failing?

Tags: html, perl, iframe, browser

My website uses iframes to call a small perl program which (using the user's ip address) returns the associated country code. This has been working fine for years. Recently the server has been reporting ...

*[Wed Mar 13 19:16:16 2019] [error] [client 66.102.6.210] Premature end of script headers: VL.PL, referer: https://www.makeyourwill.com/*

VL.PL is the perl program that returns the visitor's location.

The problem is that I cannot reproduce the error. I have tried using Chrome, Edge, Safari, Firefox and IE. I have tried with ad-blockers. I cannot think of anything else that might affect it.

I have not included any code because I don't think it is relevant, but obviously I can if you would find it helpful.

Comment: That means the program died before it get to return headers to the web server. Unless it was killed by a signal, it would have output something to its STDERR. This is usually logged by the web server. If not, reenable that.

Comment: Thanks. So if I include: open STDERR, '>&STDOUT'; in the program the error will go to a file that I can find on the server? Do you know where that would be?

Comment: Ow, no. If you do that (soon enough), the error will be sent as the response, which is bad. Do not make any changes to the script. Just check the web server's error log

Comment: All I am getting from the error log is "Premature end of script headers".

Comment: The two most likely cases are: Your web server doesn't log the STDERR of CGI programs (as most do by default), or the CGI program was killed by a signal. Both could be diagnosed by replacing the script with a wrapper that performs additional logging.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. Any chance you could point me towards an example of a wrapper performing additional logging?

Comment: I mean something like `#!/bin/sh` // `command 2>>/var/log/command` // `echo "Exited with $?" >>/var/log/command` Maybe make that last one conditional on `$?` being non-zero.

Comment: Sorry for my profound ignorance. Are you saying I should write another program that calls the problem one with the code you suggested?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was a problem with the Dreamhost server. I have not been able to squeeze the actual fault out of them, other than "may have been due to a server kernel issue". But they moved the site to a new server with a later copy of Ubuntu and the problem has disappeared.